# Shell Scripts: Nested for Loop iterating only once

Tags: shell, wget

Im trying to automate a download of multiple files from a  server. There is a nested loop structure to pass through directories. The files in one directory are numbered and I'm just iterating through them using a counter. The indication that a directory is devoid of all required files is when a 404 is encountered. However, the break statement in the if statement seems to break out of both loops during this case. I tried giving break 1 to indicate that only one loop is to be stopped, but to no avail.

```
page=$1
chapStart=$2
chapEnd=$3
k=$2
for i in {$2..$3}
do
        j=1
        while true
        do
                if ((j < 10))
                then
                        pg=0"$j"
                else
                        pg=$j
                fi
                res=$(wget --timeout=10 http://www.somesite.com/content/content/"$page"/"$k"/0"$pg".file)
                if(($? != 0))
                then
                        break 1
                fi
                let ++j
        done
        let ++k
done
```

I need the break to exit just the while loop when encountered.

**Edit**
As per chepner's correct answer, the problem was in the for loop structure rather than the break statement, which functions rather beautifully. Updated, working code is:

```
page=$1
chapStart=$2
chapEnd=$3
k=$2
for((i=$2;i<=$3;i++));
do
        j=1
        while true
        do
                if ((j < 10))
                then
                        pg=0"$j"
                else
                        pg=$j
                fi
                res=$(wget --timeout=10 http://www.somesite.com/content/content/"$page"/"$k"/0"$pg".file)
                if(($? != 0))
                then
                        break 1
                fi
                let ++j
        done
        let ++k
done
```

Comment: turn on debug/trace with `set -vx` to see if all variables are working the way you expect. Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot use parameter expansion inside brace expansions. Your outer loop only has one iteration, with `i` set to the literal string `{$2..$3}`. You should use one of

```
for ((i=$2; i<=$3; i++)); do
```

or

```
for i in $(seq $2 $3); do
```

instead.

Comment: Ooh thats embarassing. Let me just change the title